# Error using package bashful

Tags: errors, bash, bashful

Even in the simplest MWE executed on a linux distribution, the command `latex -shell-escape test.tex` returns me the error message:

```
Use of \bashIII doesn't match its definition.
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bashful}

\begin{document}
\bash
ls
\END
\end{document}
```

Maybe it is too short and simple but I like to apply to it lateron the script:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{bashful}

\begin{filecontents}{temp}
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{pdfpages}
    \begin{document}
    \includepdf{page1.pdf}
    \end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\bash
pdflatex temp.tex;
\END

\includepdf[pages=-,nup=2x2]{temp.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I know, the command lines shouldn't be in braces, but in lines by themselves; `\bash[<options>]<EOL><commands><EOL>\END`

Comment: @egreg: You mean like the corrections I applied right now?

Comment: Yes, but the compilation hangs. Of course I have not `page1.pdf`

Comment: Even as I have a file `page1.pdf`, it does return me the same error...

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{bashful}

\begin{filecontents}{strbash-temp.tex}
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{pdfpages}
    \begin{document}
    \includepdf[pages=-]{myaseen.pdf}
    \end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\bash[stdoutFile=/dev/null]
pdflatex strbash-temp.tex
\END

\includepdf[pages=-,nup=2x2]{strbash-temp.pdf}
\end{document}
```

`myaseen.pdf` is a three page file I have on my system.

[image]

Comment: Everything seems to work fine until I get an error message: L17: File /dev/nullwas empty
! Undefined control sequence.
<write> ...nputlineno : bashStderr :=
\bashStderr